# Get JSON data from API into string

Tags: php, json, api

Im trying to get some data into a string from an API..

```
<?php
 // create curl resource 
        $ch = curl_init(); 

        // set url 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.feathercoin.com/?output=usd"); 

        //return the transfer as a string 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

        // $output contains the output string 
        $result = curl_exec($ch); 


        // Will dump a beauty json :3
        var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
        // close curl resource to free up system resources 
        curl_close($ch);  
?>
```

The above gives me: array(1) { ["usd"]=> float(1.210935) }

Now all I need to do is get the 1.210935 into a string of $coinvalue.
Can anyone help me do this?!!

Thank you
Jason

Comment: json_decode returns a PHP data structure. access it like you would any OTHER php structure, e.g. an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = json_decode($result, true);
$coinvalue = (string) $result["usd"];
```

Comment: Can u help me with one more array?

Comment: {"ticker":{"high":43.99,"low":28.6,"avg":36.295,"vol":34514947.05611,"vol_cur":924541.02434,"last":34,"buy":34.006802,"sell":34.000002,"updated":1385755495,"server_time":1385755497}} - It seems this is two arrays? How would I get the value for "buy" out?

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php
Example #6 should help you out.